# Priority for linear gradient?

Tags: css, firefox, gradient, rgba

I have this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,207,0,0.85),rgba(155,257,0,0.85), rgba(55,0,255,0.2) );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#abcdef, #123456, #7890ab);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#abcdef, #123456, #7890ab);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#abcdef, #123456, #7890ab);
background: linear-gradient(#abcdef, #123456, #7890ab);
```

and found out that `Firefox` picks the last line and not the `-moz-linear-gradient`. Is there a priority for `linear-gradient`? I only want the last line as fallback.

Comment: why are you doing 2 different things?

Comment: That's not exactly how prefixes work. The *latest* versions of Firefox use `linear-gradient`, whereas older versions will rely on the prefixed `-moz-linear-gradient`. But the question by @DanielA.White remains... why do you want the fallback to be something totally different?

Comment: Before `16` version of Firefox don't need the prefix ... if you want a fallback must be the moz not the unprefixed line. http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: Then it's okay. I didn't know, that Firefox uses linear-gradient now. The other way around, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`-moz-linear-gradient` was a Mozilla vendor prefix. `CSS` vendor prefixes are a way for browser vendors to add support for new CSS features in a sort of testing and experimentation period. Vendor prefixes are used to add new features that may or may not be part of a formal specification and to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized.

The `-moz-` prefixed rules are used for compatibility with older versions (Fx 3.6 to Fx 15). `linear-gradient` (without the prefix) has been supported from Firefox 16. The browser you must have tested on must be a Firefox 16 or 16+ version which is why it picked up `linear-gradient` and not `-moz-linear-gradient`.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Hope this helps!!!